# Checking 2 rows from different tables they are the same

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables 1 is "kiraci" other is "kira". both of these tables have a "KIRACI_ID".

"kiraci KIRACI_ID" is a primary key(auto_increment). "kira KIRACI_ID" is integer.

So what I want is when I post a value I want to check if there is such a value in "kiraci KIRACI_ID" and if there is then it will set this value in "kira KIRACI_ID".

```
$id = $_POST["id"];

mysql_connect(localhost,root);
$dbname = "kiracilar";
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query= "SELECT kiraci.KIRACI_ID, kira.KIRACI_ID";
mysql_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . mysql_error()); 

$query2= "INSERT INTO kira (KIRACI_ID) VALUES ('$id')";
mysql_query($query2) or die('Query "' . $query2 . '" failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

So I need a query or something for a check between these 2 queries I think?. (Using PHP5, Phpmyadmin).

If you could help me it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query

```
$query= "SELECT kiraci.KIRACI_ID from kiraci where kiraci.KIRACI_ID ='your post value' ";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($row > 0)
{
    $query2= "INSERT INTO kira (KIRACI_ID,Kira,Odeme) VALUES ('$id','$kira','$odeme')";
    mysql_query($query2) or die('Query "' . $query2 . '" failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: this is not working like i want. it is still adding even if there is no such value "KIRACI_ID in my kiraci table"

Comment: but can I ask u something. what value is $row getting because I dont know what mysql_num_rows do. just curious

Comment: it will give you number of rows getting from the query provided.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `UNION[ALL]`:

```
SELECT KIRACI_ID
FROM kiraci
UNION
SELECT KIRACI_ID
FROM kira
```

Comment: could you explain a little more because i dont what this do.

Comment: @Mohtje61, [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) is used to combine two different result sets with each other like what you want get the id from the first table and the id from the other table. I didn't use `JOIN` because there is no need to use it here since you just need to get only the ID if you want to get extra data you should use it.

Comment: Note: this approach will fail if for any reason the ID is present in `kira`, but not in `kiraci`. The system will think the ID is present in `kiraci` and allow one further addition to `kira`. You could do `SELECT KIRACI_ID, 'kiraci' FROM kiraci WHERE KIRACI_ID = '$id' UNION SELECT KIRACI_ID, 'kira' FROM kira WHERE KIRACI_ID = '$id'` to tell between the two sources.